# I can't get the full text of the tweet

Tags: python, csv, twitter, tweepy, arabic

I can't get the full text of the Arabic tweet when I use tweet_mode='extended' and tweet.full_text.encode('utf-8') I don't know what is the problem

```
HashValue = "#لقاح"
StartDate = "2022-01-02"
csvFile = open(HashValue+'.csv', 'a',encoding='utf-8')
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
      for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                                q=HashValue,
                                count=20,
                                lang="ar",
                                since=StartDate,
                                tweet_mode='extended').items():
        
     print (tweet.created_at, tweet.full_text)
     csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.full_text.encode('utf-8')])
  print ("Scraping finished and saved to "+HashValue+".csv")
```

Comment: Do you have an explicit tweet that we can test on along with example of your current output and what you want?

Comment: `csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.full_text.encode('utf-8')])` is incorrect.  You've already opened the file as UTF-8.  `csvWriter.writerow` parameters do not need to be manually encoded again.  Write Unicode strings.